# REGEXP_REPLACE for name and surname masking

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('Tina Frederich Piedro', '\w+', '*') from table;
```

I'm using `\w+` this but it returns `* * *` what is the true regex for expected output?

Input;

```
Tina Frederich Piedro
```

Expected Output;

```
T*** F******** P*****
```

Comment: You may only hardcode the number of the asterisks - `REGEXP_REPLACE('Tina Frederich Piedro', '(\w)\w*', '\1***')`, or you will have to match and capture the `\w*` part and then add more code to replace with the exact number of asterisks.

Comment: FYI - \w also includes 0-9 and underscores (and maybe more) so that might return unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a general solution, but it might work in your case.  You can replace the *lower case* letters with `'*'`s:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('Tina Frederich Piedro', '[a-z]', '*', 1, 0, 'c')
```

The `'c'` is for a case-sensitive replace.

Comment: Surnames could contain mixed case though, like "McDonald".

Answer (score 1):

I'm by no means a regexp expert, I had to split the answer into two stages. I imagine someone more capable can combine the two steps. But this does the trick and also accounts for upper case letters in the middle of names or punctuation for example O'Brian.

```
select
     regexp_replace(lowers_done,'\*[A-Z]','**') first_letters_only
from

(
select
    regexp_replace('Tina McDonald O''Brian','[a-z]|[[:punct:]]','*') lowers_done
from
    dual
)
```

Output:

T*** M******* O******

Comment: Obviously, this can be written without a sub-query, I simply split it out to show more clearly what was going on in the two separate regexs

Answer (score 0):

If it's for security reasons you can use the DBMS_REDACT package to apply masking pattern on sensitive information. Documentation is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_redact.htm#ARPLS73800)

I'm aware it's not a regexp solution though and further more this functionality may be subject to additional licencing from oracle, but that the solution Oracle suggest to PCI compliant solution on sensitive data.